# How to retrieve data from a table and count number rows from another table then show them together in a while loop or HTML table?

Tags: php, select, join, mysqli, subquery

I need to retrieve `'projects'` details from table `'projects'`.

I need to get number of bids from `'projectsBids'`.

Then show them all in a HTML table based on project IDs

This is my `'projectsBids'` table:

```
pID  | bidder      
-----+----------------
AAAA | mark 
AAAA | pete 
AAAA | dave 
BBBB | mason
BBBB | simon
```

Following code shows number of bids for a particular project ID (pID)

```
<?php
$pID = $_GET["pID"];
$query = "SELECT pID FROM projectsBids WHERE pID='$pID'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('error');
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```

Now I want to show this count using it's `'pID'` in a HTML summary table where I am retrieve data from another table `'projects'`

`'projects'` table:

```
pID   |     pName      | pBudget 
--------------------------------
AAAA | Create Website | 250      
BBBB | Create an App  | 550
```

I am using the following code to retrieve the data..

Check 4th `<td>`(in following code) where I want to display the number of bids for that project ID.

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT pID,pName,pBudget FROM projects ORDER BY id";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['pID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['pName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['pBudget']."</td>";
        echo "<td>"**HERE I WANT TO SHOW 'Number of BIDS of PROJECT ID(pID)'**"</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Whenever I try with subquery or join it does not work..

What is the correct query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
I have tested it on your data.

SELECT *,( SELECT COUNT(pID) FROM projectsBids WHERE projectsBids.pID = projects.pID) as bids FROM projects
use this query you will get the result.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select p.pid,p.pname,p.pbudget,count(pb.bidder) as totbids from projects p left join projectsBids pb on p.pid=pb.pid group by p.pid,p.pname,p.pbudget
```

Comment: I did not downvote it.. someone else.. if I apply your query it says "`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pID in functions.php on line 30
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pName in functions.php on line 31
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pBudget in functions.php on line 32
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pRate in functions.php on line 33
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pID in functions.php on line 35`"

those lines are my php part